# How to remove from R data.frame the row of types in Jupyter?

Tags: r, dataframe, jupyter

I was using R in Jupyter and then when I outputted my data.frame, it strangely showed a row of variable's type like `<int>`, `<dbl>`. I tried to remove it but it removes either one of the actual data rows. How can I get rid of it? Thanks!

Code:

```
createTable <- function(s){
    a <- table(s)
    b <- a/sum(a)
    c <- cumsum(a)
    d <- cumsum(b)
    size <- length(a)

    dfAbs <- as.data.frame(a)
    dfRel <- as.data.frame(b)

    table <- cbind(
        q = 1:size, 
        w = dfAbs, 
        e = dfRel[,-1],
        r = c,
        t = d
    )

    rownames(table) = NULL
    colnames(table) = c("i", "xi", "fi", "fri", "Fi", "Fri")
    return(table)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By luck, I found out that if you convert your `data.frame` to a matrix, it will still be presented as a nice table in your Jupyter's notebook.

All you must be careful of is the types conversion, which in my case is numeric. Then I ran this:

```
df <- sapply(df, as.numeric)
```

When I run df:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not a row in your dataframe, it is showing you types of the column. It is the way dataframes are displayed in Jupyter. If you use RStudio you'll get the same layout for tibbles.

```
tibble::tibble(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])

#      a b    
#  <int> <chr>
#1     1 a    
#2     2 b    
#3     3 c    
#4     4 d    
#5     5 e
```

Comment: There's no way to remove it to improve presentation?

Comment: I don't use Jupyter notebooks but if you want this for presentation purposes you can try using `knitr::kable(df)` or `DT::datatable(df)` where `df` is the name of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way is to convert to `data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(out)
```